# Python - Supervisor how to log the standard output -

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, unix, supervisord

I'm not expert about python, could someone explain where is the problem?

I'd like to collect the stdout through supervisor 
http://supervisord.org/

I've made 3 different scripts that print output, for bash and PHP I can collect the output, without problems, python doesn't work.

php_test.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
    for($i=0;$i<100000;$i++){
        sleep(5);
        echo 'test';
    }
?>
```

bash_test.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in `seq 1 100000`; do
    sleep 5
    echo item: $i
done
```

python_test.sh ( with differents tests to print output )

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import time
import sys
from contextlib import redirect_stdout

for num in range(0,100000):
    time.sleep(5)
    print("test!")
    sys.stdout.write("test")
    with redirect_stdout(sys.stderr):
        print("test")
```

My supervisor config files

bash

```
[program:bash_test]
process_name=bash_test
command=/home/user/bash_test.sh
stdout_logfile=/home/user/bash_test_output.log
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0
```

php

```
[program:php_test]
process_name=php_test
command=/home/user/php_test.sh
stdout_logfile=/home/user/php_test_output.log
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0
```

python

```
[program:python_test]
process_name=python_test
command=/home/user/python_test.sh
stdout_logfile=/home/user/python_test_output.log
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0
```

Thank so much for the help.
It's driving me crazy ;[

Comment: Neither of the two output work?

Comment: PHP and BASH work fine, Python doesn't print anything.

If I execute the script with `python3 ./python_test.sh` I can see the output in the console but not in the supervisor logs ;(

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Python output is buffered, use this after print

```
sys.stdout.flush()
```

or (Python 3)

```
print(something, flush=True)
```

or better

```
import logging
logging.warning('Watch out!')
```

https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html

Answer (score 7):

You can also install a stdout friendly version using `pip install supervisor-stdout`
. Find the usage instructions [here](https://github.com/coderanger/supervisor-stdout).

UPDATE:
you can also update your `supervisord.conf` to point the output to stdout.

```
[program:worker2]
command=bash yourscript.sh
stdout_logfile=/dev/stdout
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0
```